# "People believed the earth is flat" or "People believed the earth was flat." : Which is correct?

Tags: grammar

"People believed the earth is flat." vs. "People believed the earth was flat."

Which sentence is grammatically correct? Or are both correct?
Now I got to know "The earth is flat" is the title of a bestseller. 
What about the latter? I think it's also correct, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. It's called mixing the tenses. Both are **correct**.

If you say:

> People believed (that) the earth is flat means
>   **In the past**, people believed that (**as a fact until the moment people believed at that time and they believed that it would be so in the future**) that the earth is flat.

compare with:

> People believed (that) the earth was flat (The fact was already obsolete)
>   means **In the past**, people believed that (**the earth is not flat anymore, it used to be flat, but at the moment of speaking people stopped believing**) that the earth was flat.

**Explanation:**

> **Reported speech and reported thoughts** have their **own time**.

When you're reporting what someone said or thought, there are two different times to think about:

```
*the time when the person said it or thought it*

*the time that the person was speaking or thinking about*
```

> The first clause is reflected in words like "**_ said" or "_**
>   believed"
>
> The second clause and the rest of the sentence are usually the
>   explanation.

*Both of the verbs of the subject in the main sentences are in past tense, so the sentences carry the past tense.*

**[Important Source](https://www.phrasemix.com/answers/why-do-english-speakers-mix-present-and-past-tense)**

**[Source](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/sequence.htm)**